# Running a JAR file with cron on server?

Tags: java, cron, hosting

I have written a java program which does some calculations then sends an email. I have packaged it as a jar. I need to run this program every week at midnight on Thursday. The chances are my computer is not going to be on all the time so I'll need it to run from some host. My question is - Is there a free hosting place which supports cron and java?

Hmm, I had a look at app engine but got stuck trying to install the Google plugin for eclipse. It brought up an error after clicking to install..

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)
Missing requirement: Google App Engine Plugin 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.appengine.eclipse.core 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)
To: com.google.appengine.eclipse.core [3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.e37.feature.feature.group 2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)
To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google App Engine:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/

It supports Java, and it's free within some quota.

Note that it does not support running desktop applications, but since you wrote your code in Java, it's most likely portable, and you can also take advantage of the App Engine platform services like sending emails. It also has a cron service.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up an Amazon Micro Instance Server.  They are free and give you complete control of the machine including setting up cron jobs.

[AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)

Comment: This looks promising! Are you sure it's free to use? I've had to enter my credit card details already!

Comment: Yes you have to enter a credit card but you will not be charged.  I'm currently running 3 of them :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenShift ( https://openshift.redhat.com/app/ ).

The offer a free series of tools for small needs, and the ability to scale up from there.